# Skype crashes at start even after deleting all settings

Tags: macos, crash, skype, osx-yosemite

I've got latest Skype 7.10 on Yosemite 10.10.3.
I used it last week and it worked flawlessly but today it 'quits unexpectedly' every time I start it.

I already went to https://support.skype.com/EN/faq/FA10916/why-does-skype-for-mac-os-x-crash-my-computer

I deleted `~/Library/Application Support/Skype` and `~/Library/Preferences, delete the file .com.skype.skype.plist` but it still keeps crashing.

**What else can I try?**

Answer (score 0):

Other things to try...

- Delete the Saved state folder, at `~/Library/Saved Application State/com.skype.skype.savedState`
- Fix Permmissions, Check & if necessary Repair Disk from Disk Utility.
- Boot into Safe Mode [hold  <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>  at the chimes] Allow 5 mins after you get to the Finder, then reboot again.

I'd also update to 10.10.4 using the [combo updater](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1820), that may fix a lot of things.